# URLEncodedUtils deprecated in Android

Tags: java, android, apache, httprequest

`URLEncodedUtils` is deprecated in Android API 22+. What could I use instead in this code?

I need to change `URLEncode.Utils.Format()` line.

```
public String construct() {
  return (iftrue? HOSTING_NAME : _NAME) + yDomain
         + (param.size() > 0 ? "?" 
         + URLEncodedUtils.format(yParam, "utf-8") : "");
}
```

Comment: use a decent network lib that does it for you

Comment: Could you please give me some examples? I am a bit new to Android development

Answer (score 0):

You can use java inbuilt method java.net.URLEncoder to construct url with param data.  URLEncoder.encode(yParam, "UTF-8")

Change your method and check it.

```
`public String construct() {
    return (iftrue? HOSTING_NAME : _NAME) + yDomain
            + (param.size() > 0 ? "?" + URLEncoder.encode(yParam, "UTF-8"): "");}`
```

Comment: Seems to be ok, but gives me an error with yParam. My yParam is: List<Pair<String, String>> mParameters = new ArrayList<>();            Maybe I should change it into something else?